# Checking byte[] in dataset

Tags: c#, dataset, byte

I have an app for pictures that can be added to sql database with some information.. I keep pictures as `varbinary` in sql table. I want to check whether the picture was added before. my code as follows:

```
byte[] img = File.ReadAllBytes(item);
//that converts the file to bytearray

string str = ByteString(img); 
//ByteString is a method that converts bytearray to string (It works)

DataRow[] satirlar = das.Tables[0].Select("PicBinary=" + str); 
//sql table keeps picture as varbinary in PicBinary Column

if (satirlar[0]!=null)
{
    //codes
    continue;
}
```

but I get an exception like ("column (//something unreadable) not found") over my `das.Tables[0].Select command`.. Any advice?

Comment: Which language you're talking about, .Net/C#? Please add the correct tags.

Comment: How are you filling das?

Comment: `if(satirlar[0] != null)` should be replaced with `if(satirlar.Count > 0)`

Comment: Jay Patel - with SqlDataAdapter (dap.fill(das, Tables[//tablename]) (SqlSelectCommand cmd=select * from //tablename);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought is that "something unreadable" is the string representation of the contents of the image file and `Select` is treating the right hand side of the expression `"PicBinary=" + str` as a column name since it's not quoted.

That said, I'm not certain that `DataTable`'s `Select` method will allow you to do the comparison this way. You might want to look in to [LINQ to DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977.aspx) (as recommended by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136657/datatable-select-with-byte-array-vb-net) answer) to do a byte-by-byte comparison of the data from your file and the contents of each cell in that column.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add correct `Escape Sequences` when passing the string variable in `select`.

**Update**:

I might have been wrong.

Try passing parameter as following?

```
SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@PicBinary", SqlDbType.VarBinary, buffer.Length);
parameter.Value = buffer;
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(parameter);
```

where `buffer` is your input data for the query.

Comment: Which escape sequences? Could you post a link to reference material so the OP has a place to look in to how adjust the data appropriately please?

Comment: @mlorbetske I have edited my post. I thought of escape sequence problem when I saw the data was being passed as string but I am wrong. I think trying it the way I mentioned in the edit might be a solution.